# How to unit-test a decorator which uses environment variable?

Tags: python, django

I created a decorator to allow functions be be run in specific environments only:

```
def accepted_environments(*envs):
    """
    The decorated function can be executed only in specified envs
    """
    def my_decorator(func_to_be_decorated):
        def wrapper():
            if settings.ENV_NAME not in envs:
                raise EnvironmentException
            return func_to_be_decorated()
        return wrapper
    return my_decorator

# Usage example
@accepted_environments('local', 'prod')
def hello():
    print("hello")
```

That seems to work, but I'd like to unit test it.
The problem is: my tests are potentialy run in every environment (local, staging, prod). Plus, I think it's not safe my tests are able to change environment variables.

Should I "mock" this behaviour? How would you do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mock` to override the value of `settings.ENV_NAME` for a test.

```
def test_not_in_dev(self):
    with mock.patch.dict(settings.__dict__, ENV_NAME="dev"):
        self.assertRaises(EnvironmentException, hello)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. mock.patch.objet does not exist (I'm using Python 3.5). I tried with `with mock.patch(settings, ENV_NAME="env1")` but I get a `AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`

Comment: Are you importing 3rd-party `mock` module? https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#patch-object

Comment: Nope, it's just Pycharm..weird. Otherwise, I get a `TypeError: _patch_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'attribute'` I'm trying to find out in the doc what mock needs :)

Comment: OK, I think I've fixed it (clearly, I didn't not remember how to use `patch.object` correctly). I'm not a big fan of this answer; I was thinking of `patch.dict` all along, but using it with the `__dict__` attribute leaves a bad taste in my mouth.

Comment: Ok, makes sens :) Thanks.